# Curl call to bigcommerce site with no response

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I'm trying to make a curl call to a bigcommerce store locally, but I'm getting no response. The store is hosted in a different domain. When the api url is executed manually it works.

I checked for the `curl_error` and it seems to be the following error:

> < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently..

This is the sample code

```
<?php
$api_url = 'site url/api/v2/blog/posts/count';
$fp = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/errorlog.txt', 'w');
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept:application/json','Content-Length: 0'));                                   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:passwd" ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you get indicates that the document you want to access has moved, and the API responds with the new location to follow. Just tell cURL to follow this new location by setting the **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION** option to *true*:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Victor T.